# Is it possible to log the output of MarkupTemplateEngine in grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

I am using groovys MarkupTemplateEngine to craft a xml like response for a calling application - to help in tracing issues I would like to log within my application the responses being provided to the calling app. Essentially i am looking to see if it is possible to log the generated template as returned to the client?

edit: So far I have tried using a response interceptor to access the response fields in both the after and afterview events with no luck

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add your approach to the question.

Comment: Thanks, added a little more info to the description, not really too sure where to start with this one but have tried using an interceptor to get the response

Answer (score 0):

in log4j there is a special builder that could wrap your original writer and will write output into two destinations: log and original writer. (or it could be outputstream)

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-iostreams/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/io/IoBuilder.html

```
Writer loggingWriter = IoBuilder.
    forLogger(your_class_or_logger).
    filter(original_writer).
    buildWriter();
```